# JS, setTimout function executes before the specified interval

Tags: javascript

The below code is to log `count` to console in each seconds, after 4 seconds it will stop

As you can infer from below, the setTimout function execute before 4 seconds and program fail

```
   let count=0;
    let intid = setInterval(counter,1000)
    
    function counter(){
    console.log(++count)
    }
    
    setTimeout(clearInterval(intid),4000)
```

When I change to this format  `setTimeout(()=>clearInterval(intid),4000)` , it works well.

Why did it execute before hitting 4 s ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4smgbLy2/

Answer (score 1):

You are calling clearInterval and then send the result to the setTimeout function, when you write `setTimeout(() => clearInterval(intid), 4000)` you are sending the function and the result of the call